# Powershell - Change to MB instead of GB

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

So basically I have a script whereby:

```
$MailboxArray = New-Object System.Object

$MailboxArray | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -value $mail.issuewarningquota -Name WarningQuota
```

and where $mail:

```
$mail = get-mailbox -id $_
```

Now it works great in a For loop to get info for every mailbox in Exchange, but I would like the IssueWarningQuota output to be in `MB` and not `GB`.

I have a method in place for the TotalItemSize where:

```
TotalItemSize.value.ToMB()
```

But this doesn't/won't work for IssueWarningQuota, any way around this?

Comment: It generates an error saying I cannot call that on the expression.

Comment: It can't convert Unlimited to MB

Comment: You're going to have to test for that, and not call that method on any of them that are set to 'unlimited'.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the syntax for thoes exchange commands but if the TotoalItemSize is a number PowerShell is really good at calculating MB and GB.

Example:

```
PS C:\> $number = 4294967296
PS C:\> $number / 1GB
4
PS C:\> $number / 1MB
4096
```

So as long as it is a number like Int32 or Double you should be able to do something like that to it to convert to MB.

Answer (score 0):

```
$MBXs = Get-Mailbox -Server Server01 -ResultSize unlimited |
 Where {$_.UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults -eq $false} 

 &{
 foreach ($MBX in $MBXs)
 {
  New-Object psobject -Property @{
   Displayname = $MBX.Displayname
   'WarningQuota (MB)' = ($MBX.IssueWarningQuota).Value.ToMB()
   'ProhibitSendQuota (MB)' = ($MBX.ProhibitSendQuota).Value.ToMB()
   'TotalItemSize (MB)' = (Get-MailboxStatistics $MBX).TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()
   }
  }
 } | Select Displayname,'WarningQuota (MB)','ProhibitSendQuota (MB)','TotalItemSize (MB)'
```